# I got a problem where I've to convert a sequence of octets into hexadecimal digits with 2 byte offset

Tags: bit-manipulation, iot

This sample represents an example of Composition Data . The data below is a
sequence of octets.

`0C001A0001000800030000010501000000800100001003103F002A00`

To help with parsing of this sequence of octets, it has been formatted with appropriate spacing characters.

`0C00 1A00 0100 0800 0300 0001 05 01 0000 0080 0100 0010 0310 3F002A00`

Note: The composition data is little-endian.

CID is 0x000C

- PID is 0x001A
- VID is 0x0001
- CRPL is 0x0008
- Features is 0x0003
- Relay and Friend features
- Loc is “front” – 0x0100
- NumS is 5
- NumV is 1

Comment: What language are you using? Converting octet to hex is easiest if you convert the octets to decimal first, then to hex.

Comment: usind node.js but getting problem in converting 2 chars (in string) to 1 byte

Comment: function myFunction() {
  
  
  var myString = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
  
   var typedArray = System.Convert.FromHexString(myString) ;
   
   var arr1 = Uint16Array.from(typedArray);
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(arr1.byteLength); 

  
   

  var view = new DataView(buffer, 0, 2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = view.getUint16(2);

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in javascript

```js
var octet = 1427;
console.log('Octal: '+octet);

var o1 = octet % 10;
var o2 = Math.floor(octet/10) % 10;
var o3 = Math.floor(octet/100) % 10;
var o4 = Math.floor(octet/1000) % 10;


o1 *= 1;
o2 *= 8;
o3 *= 64;
o4 *= 512;

var dec = o1 + o2 + o3 + o4;
console.log('Decimal: '+dec);

var hex = "";
var a = '0123456789ABCDEF';

while (dec > 0){

    var h = dec % 16;
  
    hex = a[h] + hex;
    dec = Math.floor(dec/16);
}


console.log('Hex: '+hex);
```

Above was showing the hard way, since I didn't know what language you had at the time I starting writing it. Below is a simple javascript way:

```
octet = 1477;
decimal = parseInt(octet.toString(), 8);
hex = decimal.toString(16);
console.log(hex);
```